# Need help in understanding Dynamic Programming approach for "balanced 0-1 matrix"?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem: I am struggling to understand/visualize the Dynamic Programming approach for "A type of balanced 0-1 matrix in "Dynamic Programming - Wikipedia Article."

Wikipedia Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#A_type_of_balanced_0.E2.80.931_matrix

I couldn't understand how the memoization works when dealing with a multidimensional array. For example, when trying to solve the Fibonacci series with DP, using an array to store previous state results is easy, as the index value of the array store the solution for that state.

Can someone explain DP approach for the "0-1 balanced matrix" in simpler manner?

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia offered both a crappy explanation and a not ideal algorithm.  But let's work with it as a starting place.

First let's take the backtracking algorithm.  Rather than put the cells of the matrix "in some order", let's go everything in the first row, then everything in the second row, then everything in the third row, and so on.  Clearly that will work.

Now let's modify the backtracking algorithm slightly.  Instead of going cell by cell, we'll go row by row.  So we make a list of the `n choose n/2` possible rows which are half 0 and half 1.  Then have a recursive function that looks something like this:

```
def count_0_1_matrices(n, filled_rows=None):
    if filled_rows is None:
        filled_rows = []
    if some_column_exceeds_threshold(n, filled_rows):
        # Cannot have more than n/2 0s or 1s in any column
        return 0
    else:
        answer = 0
        for row in possible_rows(n):
            answer = answer + count_0_1_matrices(n, filled_rows + [row])
        return answer
```

This is a backtracking algorithm like what we had before.  We are just doing whole rows at a time, not cells.

But notice, we're passing around more information than we need.  There is no need to pass in the exact arrangement of rows.  All that we need to know is how many 1s are needed in each remaining column.  So we can make the algorithm look more like this:

```
def count_0_1_matrices(n, still_needed=None):
    if still_needed is None:
        still_needed = [int(n/2) for _ in range(n)]

    # Did we overrun any column?
    for i in still_needed:
        if i < 0:
            return 0

    # Did we reach the end of our matrix?
    if 0 == sum(still_needed):
        return 1

    # Calculate the answer by recursion.
    answer = 0
    for row in possible_rows(n):
        next_still_needed = [still_needed[i] - row[i] for i in range(n)]
        answer = answer + count_0_1_matrices(n, next_still_needed)

    return answer
```

This version is almost the recursive function in the Wikipedia version.  The main difference is that our base case is that after every row is finished, we need nothing, while Wikipedia would have us code up the base case to check the last row after every other is done.

To get from this to a top-down DP, you only need to memoize the function.  Which in Python you can do by defining then adding an `@memoize` decorator.  Like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrap
```

But remember that I criticized the Wikipedia algorithm?  Let's start improving it!  The first big improvement is this.  Do you notice that the order of the elements of `still_needed` can't matter, just their values?  So just sorting the elements will stop you from doing the calculation separately for each permutation.  (There can be a lot of permutations!)

```
@memoize
def count_0_1_matrices(n, still_needed=None):
    if still_needed is None:
        still_needed = [int(n/2) for _ in range(n)]

    # Did we overrun any column?
    for i in still_needed:
        if i < 0:
            return 0

    # Did we reach the end of our matrix?
    if 0 == sum(still_needed):
        return 1

    # Calculate the answer by recursion.
    answer = 0
    for row in possible_rows(n):
        next_still_needed = [still_needed[i] - row[i] for i in range(n)]
        answer = answer + count_0_1_matrices(n, sorted(next_still_needed))

    return answer
```

That little innocuous `sorted` doesn't look important, but it saves a lot of work!  And now that we know that `still_needed` is always sorted, we can simplify our checks for whether we are done, and whether anything went negative.  Plus we can add an easy check to filter out the case where we have too many 0s in a column.

```
@memoize
def count_0_1_matrices(n, still_needed=None):
    if still_needed is None:
        still_needed = [int(n/2) for _ in range(n)]

    # Did we overrun any column?
    if still_needed[-1] < 0:
        return 0

    total = sum(still_needed)
    if 0 == total:
        # We reached the end of our matrix.
        return 1
    elif total*2/n < still_needed[0]:
        # We have total*2/n rows left, but won't get enough 1s for a
        # column.
        return 0

    # Calculate the answer by recursion.
    answer = 0
    for row in possible_rows(n):
        next_still_needed = [still_needed[i] - row[i] for i in range(n)]
        answer = answer + count_0_1_matrices(n, sorted(next_still_needed))

    return answer
```

And, assuming you implement `possible_rows`, this should both work and be significantly more efficient than what Wikipedia offered.

=====

Here is a complete working implementation.  On my machine it calculated the 6'th term in under 4 seconds.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrap

@memoize
def count_0_1_matrices(n, still_needed=None):
    if 0 == n:
        return 1

    if still_needed is None:
        still_needed = [int(n/2) for _ in range(n)]

    # Did we overrun any column?
    if still_needed[0] < 0:
        return 0

    total = sum(still_needed)
    if 0 == total:
        # We reached the end of our matrix.
        return 1
    elif total*2/n < still_needed[-1]:
        # We have total*2/n rows left, but won't get enough 1s for a
        # column.
        return 0
    # Calculate the answer by recursion.
    answer = 0
    for row in possible_rows(n):
        next_still_needed = [still_needed[i] - row[i] for i in range(n)]
        answer = answer + count_0_1_matrices(n, tuple(sorted(next_still_needed)))

    return answer

@memoize
def possible_rows(n):
    return [row for row in _possible_rows(n, n/2)]


def _possible_rows(n, k):
    if 0 == n:
        yield tuple()
    else:
        if k < n:
            for row in _possible_rows(n-1, k):
                yield tuple(row + (0,))
        if 0 < k:
            for row in _possible_rows(n-1, k-1):
                yield tuple(row + (1,))

n = 2
if 1 < len(argv):
    n = int(argv[1])

print(count_0_1_matrices(2*n)))
```

Comment: If you have time, can you please demonstrate that sorting works? Perhaps by confirming the results of your program with https://oeis.org/A058527 ? Something doesn't sit right with me about that but I've yet to try and think it through.

Comment: Also, if youre only counting stil-needed 1's, how will your function make sure there is a matching set of zeros in each column, without also passing `k` as an argument? It would help to see a working version.

Comment: After fixing some tiny bugs, I have a working implementation.  It produces correct answer.  As for why sorting works, any permutation of columns for a 0-1 matrix produces another 0-1 matrix.  This produces a bijection between the count of ways to finish with one `still_needed` and the sorted version of the same.  As for a matching set of 0s, that is guaranteed by the fact that if the sum of the elements in the column comes out right, and it only contains 1s and 0s, then the number of 0s must be right as well.

Comment: Oh, right, if we keep placeholders for zero-needed, and your `possible_rows` can only assign at most `n/2` 1's then we don't need `k` for reference. I'm glad sorting works, it means it's a simpler more intuitive solution than any Inclusion–exclusion I might get boggled in.

Answer (score 2):

You're memoizing states that are likely to be repeated. The state that needs to be remembered in this case is the vector (`k` is implicit). Let's look at one of the examples you [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#A_type_of_balanced_0.E2.80.931_matrix) to. Each pair in the vector argument (of length `n`) is representing "the number of zeros and ones that have yet to be placed in that column."

Take the example on the left, where the vector is `((1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1)), when k = 2` and the assignments leading to it were `1  0  1  0, k = 3` and `0  1  0  1, k = 4`. But we could get to the same state, `((1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1)), k = 2` from a different set of assignments, for example: `0  1  0  1, k = 3` and `1  0  1  0, k = 4`. If we would memoize the result for the state, `((1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1))`, we could avoid recalculating the recursion for that branch again.

Please let me know if there's anything I could better clarify.

Further elaboration in response to your comment:

The Wikipedia example seems to be pretty much a brute-force with memoization. The algorithm seems to attempt to enumerate all the matrixes but uses memoization to exit early from repeated states. How do we enumerate all possibilities? To take their example, `n = 4`, we start with the vector `[(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)]` where zeros and ones are yet to be placed. (Since the sum of each tuple in the vector is `k`, we could have a simpler vector where `k` and the count of either ones or zeros is maintained.)

At every stage, `k`, in the recursion, we enumerate all possible configurations for the next vector. If the state exists in our hash, we simply return the value for that key. Otherwise, we assign the vector as a new key in the hash (in which case this recursion branch will continue).

For example:

```
Vector                       [(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)]

Possible assignments of 1's: [1 1 0 0], [1 0 1 0], [1 0 0 1] ... etc.

First branch:                [(2,1),(2,1),(1,2),(1,2)]
  is this vector a key in the hash?
  if yes, return value lookup
  else, assign this vector as a key in the hash where the value is the sum 
     of the function calls with the next possible vectors as their arguments
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, I see the logic is to memoize the vector of pairs for each row. Does this mean each time the states are generated from the vector pairs?. Could you please explain the Wikipedia article in a different way, i really couldn't understand anything in that explanation after the first line. Or can we use Backtrack method suggested by @btilly and modify it to recursively call each row instead of cells. Here is my implementation using Backtrack [link](https://github.com/ruthra-kumar/Sieve-of-Eratosthenes---C--/blob/master/Balanced_0-1_matrix_Backtrack.cpp)

Comment: @RuthraKumar Yes, each state that is generated must be checked against the hash to avoid repeating the remaining recursion for it. I elaborated a bit more in the answer. Please let me know if I can clarify something further.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/585411/btilly, I've updated their algorithm to  exclude "0" cases in the `still_needed` tuple. The code is about 50% faster largely because of more cache hits using the collapsable tuple.

```
import time
from typing import Tuple
from sys import argv
from functools import cache

@cache
def possible_rows(n, k=None) -> Tuple[int]:
    if k is None:
        k = n / 2
    return [row for row in _possible_rows(n, k)]


def _possible_rows(n, k) -> Tuple[int]:
    if 0 == n:
        yield tuple()
    else:
        if k < n:
            for row in _possible_rows(n-1, k):
                yield tuple(row + (0,))
        if 0 < k:
            for row in _possible_rows(n-1, k-1):
                yield tuple(row + (1,))

def count(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    still_needed = tuple([k] * n)
    return count_0_1_matrices(k, still_needed)

@cache
def count_0_1_matrices(k:int, still_needed: Tuple[int]):
    """
    Assume still_needed contains only positive ints, and is sorted ascending
    """
    # Calculate the answer by recursion.
    answer = 0
    for row in possible_rows(len(still_needed), k):
        # Decrement the still_needed value tuple by the row tuple and only keep positive results. Sorting is important for cache hits.
        next_still_needed = tuple(sorted([sn - r for sn, r in zip(still_needed, row) if sn > r]))

        # Only continue if we still need values and there are enough rows left
        if not next_still_needed:
            answer += 1

        elif len(next_still_needed) >= k and sum(next_still_needed) >= next_still_needed[-1] * k:
            # sum / k -> how many rows left. We need enough rows left to continue down this path.
            answer += count_0_1_matrices(k, next_still_needed)

    return answer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 7
    if 1 < len(argv):
        n = int(argv[1])
    start = time.time()
    result = count(2*n, n)
    print(f"{result} in {time.time() - start} seconds")
```